# How do i put the enemy in an idle state without breaking everything

Tags: 3d, gdscript, godot-3

very simple logic but my brain is fried for now, so I don't get how to ad the option for an enemy to sometimes just go idle without breaking the entire animation logic... i tried adding a randomized timer so that when the enemy is already walking randomly and there are no players around the timer will switch idle and walk on and off...but for some reason this glitched the enemy and it started rotating on itself randomly and then stopped moving completely, so here's what works for now :

```
extends KinematicBody

onready var animation = $Archer/AnimationPlayer
onready var eyes = $Eyes
onready var ray = $RayCast
var directionChangeTimer = 0.0
var directionChangeInterval = 0.0
const minChangeInterval = 3.0
const maxChangeInterval = 12.0
const turn = 32
var vertical_velocity = Vector3()
var gravity = 30
var state = walk
var target


#states list
enum {
    idle,
    chase,
    walk,
    shoot,
}


#as soon as the enemy spawns it will walk around randomly
func _ready():
    state = walk
    directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)

#if in range, the enemy will start attacking, 
#if outside of range the enemy will start chasing the player 
func _on_Sight_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        state = shoot
    else: 
        state = idle 

func _on_Sight_body_exited(body):
    state = chase

func changeRandomDirection():
    var randomDirection = Vector3(rand_range(-1, 1), 0, rand_range(-1, 1)).normalized()
    var lookRotation = randomDirection.angle_to(Vector3.FORWARD)
    rotate_y(lookRotation)

func getSlideVelocity():
    var forwardVector = -transform.basis.z
    return forwardVector * 4

#state machine logic
func _process(delta):
    match state:
        idle:
            animation.play("idle")
        shoot:
            animation.play("shoot")
            if target:
                eyes.look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
                rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
        walk:
            animation.play("walk")
            directionChangeTimer += delta
            if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
                directionChangeTimer = 0.0
                directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
                changeRandomDirection()
            move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity())
        chase:
            animation.play("walk", 0, 1.5)
            if target:
                var targetDirection = (target.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin).normalized()
                eyes.look_at(global_transform.origin + targetDirection, Vector3.UP)
                rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
                move_and_slide(targetDirection * getSlideVelocity().length())

#gravity without sliding on slopes
func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_on_floor():
        vertical_velocity += Vector3.DOWN * gravity * 2 * delta
    else:
        vertical_velocity = -get_floor_normal() * gravity / 2.5

    move_and_slide(vertical_velocity, Vector3.UP)

#if outside of chasing range the enemy will walk randomly,
#otherwise it will chase the player 
func _on_ChaseRange_body_entered(body):
    state = chase
    target = body
func _on_ChaseRange_body_exited(body):
    state = walk
```

Comment: if you are wondering how damage works, i usually remove irrilevant parts of code but it's just an attack function that is called by an animation frame, the attack function has an area node with a collision shape, if there are characters that can be hit in the area, then they are hit and all the damage logic happens. if it is really important, the func attack() is never called in any state but just in animations using the call method track in the animation player.

Answer (score 1):

You already have some timer logic to change the walking direction on random intervals. You could have it use a random to decide if it will change direction or switch to idle.

Something like this:

```
directionChangeTimer += delta
if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
    directionChangeTimer = 0.0
    directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
    if randf() > 0.25: # 75% chance of changing direction, 25% of going idle
        changeRandomDirection()
    else:
        state = idle
```

And the same logic on the idle state could be used to change to walk. When you do the change form idle to walk you, you probably want to have it pick a walking direction.

So:

```
match state:
    idle:
        animation.play("idle")
        directionChangeTimer += delta
        if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
            directionChangeTimer = 0.0
            directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
            changeRandomDirection()
            state = walk
    shoot:
        animation.play("shoot")
        if target != null:
            eyes.look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
            rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
    walk:
        animation.play("walk")
        directionChangeTimer += delta
        if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
            directionChangeTimer = 0.0
            directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
           if randf() > 0.75:
               changeRandomDirection()
           else:
               state = idle

        move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity())
```

Here I'm using the same time variables. I expect no issue from doing that. Although you might want to move the timer logic to a method that you can call:

```
func change_time(delta:float) -> bool:
    directionChangeTimer += delta
    if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
        directionChangeTimer = 0.0
        directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
        return true

    return false
```

Then the above code would be like this:

```
match state:
    idle:
        animation.play("idle")
        if change_time(delta):
            changeRandomDirection()
            state = walk
    shoot:
        animation.play("shoot")
        if target != null:
            eyes.look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
            rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
    walk:
        animation.play("walk")
        if change_time(delta):
           if randf() > 0.75:
               changeRandomDirection()
           else:
               state = idle

        move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity())
```

This is not for performance, this for making the code easier to read, and also to remove any error that might be introduced in duplicating the code, plus if you need to change that logic in the future you only need to change it in one place.

---

You say that in your attempt that it ended up "rotating on itself randomly ". Which suggests to me it was calling `changeRandomDirection` every frame. That could have been that you didn't reset the time correctly, or you didn't change the state when you should have.

---

About your edits to the question:

Yes, if `target` is an object then `if target:` and `if target != null:` are the same thing. However, if `target` is a `Node` then the variable it will not become `null` when the `Node` is freed... For that you check like this: `if is_instance_valid(target):`.

*I don't get the logic behind the changes of state for `Sight` and `ChaseRange`, but you do you.*

---

By the way, in a [prior question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/206257/10408) you asked about performance. Here is something you can try: Do more in `_physics_process` and less in `_process`. I believe that calling `move_and_slide` in `_process` might be having a negative impact on the performance... In particular if your machine can run at more FPS than the `physics_ticks_per_second` (which is 60 by default), and I believe it can, then it would be trying to run `_process` at that rate, so if you move that code to `_physics_process` would result in doing it *less often*.

Comment: thx, between "I don't get the logic behind the changes of state for Sight and ChaseRange, but you do you." I don't either but apparently it fixed a bug that I didn't notice prior, the enemy would randomly decide to follow the player even when outside of range, but it happened quite rarely...

Comment: and about the performance, with a huge amount of enemies i do get random drops in fps, but cpu never surpasses 12% and gpu barely reaches 19% so for now its something that goes in the ''il fix it later" list and the drops in fps are quite more rare than before.